# double values in model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have complex model with double values...I have problem with pass them into object. When I pass integer values (like 4 or 5) everything is ok, but when I try pass double value (like 4.3 or -23.3) during debugging I see that model has 0.0.

```
public class Coordinates
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Place place)
    {
        var updatedPlace = db.Place.Include(c => c.Country).Include(c => c.Coordinates).Where(p => p.ID == place.ID).SingleOrDefault();
        updatedPlace.Coordinates.Latitude = place.Coordinates.Latitude;
        updatedPlace.Coordinates.Longitude = place.Coordinates.Longitude;
        updatedPlace.Country = db.Country.Find(place.Country.ID);
        updatedPlace.Description = place.Description;
        updatedPlace.Name = place.Name;
        db.Entry(updatedPlace).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

In view I use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Coordinates.Latitude)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Coordinates.Longitude)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default model binder uses the current culture setting when parsing the request values into your model properties. So for example if you have culture set to `auto` then it will use that of the client browser (`Accept-Language` HTTP request header). And if you have a client from France (`fr-FR`) and he enters `4.3` in the input field the default model binder won't be able to parse it back to a double because in France they use `,` as decimal separator not `.`.

So you could set the culture in the web.config to some fixed value:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

Or if you need to support multiple scenarios and cultures you could also write a custom model binder.